# регулярные выражения - извлечь картинки и css файлы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте!

Допустим есть  текст:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<div class="custom">
    <p><a href="/" title="IP-телефония"><img src="/images/logo2-2-fixed-mini-3.png" alt="IP-телефония" width="175" height="44" /></a></p>
<p><a href="/news" title="IP-телефония"><img src="/logo2-2-fixed-mini.png" alt="IP-телефония" width="175" height="43" title="IP-телефония" /></a></p>
<img src="/images/24.jpg">
</div>
```

Нужно извлечь  путь до файла с названием самого файла. У файлов могут быть разные расширениями.

Т.е  на выходе должно получиться следующее:

1. href="/css/style.css"
2. src="/images/logo2-2-fixed-mini-3.png"
3. src="/logo2-2-fixed-mini.png"
4. src="/images/24.jpg"

Моя регулярка отрабатывает криво (захватывает  все до того момента, пока не найдет расширение файла).

```
/(href|src)=".*(\.png|\.js|\.css|\.jpg)"/U
```

Получаются так:

```
href="/" title="IP-телефония"><img src="/images/logo2-2-fixed-mini-3.png"
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Верным будет вот такое выражение:

```
/(href|src)=("|')([^"']*(\.png|\.js|\.css|\.jpg))("|')/
```

`[^"']` - все символы, кроме кавычек

`("|')` - кавычки могут быть разными

плюс скобки вокруг имени файла, чтобы вытащить то, что вам нужно

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит использовать регулярки для парсинга html. Это тема размыта уже до нельзя.

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

первый же пример библиотеки simplehtml
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

так же и в php есть функции для парсинга
http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtml.php
если больше вдоваться в подробности. 
А на stackoverflow.com есть такой ответ:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags
и он фиеричен помоему

> Ты не можешь парсить [X]HTML регуляркой. Потому что HTML не может быть
>   разобран через них. Регулярка не тот иинструмент который может
>   правильно разбить html на ноды. Как я много отвечал на подобные
>   вопросы. Регулярки это простые инструменты для разбора строки, для
>   html они не подойдут так как html не язык который использует
>   выражения, а язык разметки, который имеет более сложную структуру, по
>   этому регулярное выражение не может быть использованно для парсинга
>   html.  /*** тут я опускаю перевод** / Каждый раз когда вы пытаетесь
>   разобрать html регуляркой, ребёнок одержимый бесом рыдает кровью
>   девствениц а Русские хакеры ломают ваше Веб-приложение. Разбор html
>   регулярным выражением подобен вызову мёртвых душ в царство живых. 
>   / **тут автор описывает на сколько плохо поддерживать такой код ***/